# Java enum with dynamic value fields?

Tags: java, enums

I have an `Enum` for attributes of resources which has some common attributes and some resource specific attributes.

```
public enum Attributes {

//Common Attributes
    U_RESOURCETYPE("resourceType","ty"),
    U_RESOURCEID("resourceID","ri"),
    U_RESOURCENAME("resourceName","rn"),
    U_PARENTID("parentID","pi"),


    //Resource1 Attributes
    ...

    //Resource2 attributes
    ...     

    private String shortName;
    private String longName;
}
```

So currently I maintain two fields `shortName`, `longName` of these attributes.

Now I have a new field RW (read write), which tells whether this attribute is read write or not.

So I will add a field like this:

```
U_RESOURCETYPE("resourceType","ty", true);
```

So the issue arises with common attributes as they will have different RW value for different resources. For ex: `U_RESOURCETYPE` may have RW `true` for resource1 and `false` for resource2.

How to maintain values for the common attributes ?? 
For resource specific attributes there is no issue as it's unique.

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose of an `enum`. Either, those are two different enum values (e.g. `U_RESOURCETYPE` and `U_RESOURCETYPE_RW`), or it is a property of the type that is using the enum.

Comment: @NilsH:  You suggesting that I should create a separate enum for holding RW property ? So this enum will have only RW attributes

Comment: An enum should be constant, so yes, either do that or put that dynamic state somewhere else.

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha: He suggested that you are trying to store the RW flag in the wrong place to begin with. It should be another property of whatever you are flagging with your enum values.

Comment: @Wormbo: Plz check the edit in the question. I didn't get the second line "It should be another property of whatever you are flagging with your enum values" ??

Comment: @NilsH: Adding a separate enum, will create duplicate fields. Like Resource1 attribute will be there in both enums. Is that ok?

Comment: If it is read-only in one place and read-write in another then either it's not a "common attribute" or the mutability is an attribute of the JOIN of the attribute and its usage location.  Your model is wrong. Actually, you could define another enum describing all the places attributes are used and add an `EnumMap` to each attribute value to hold the mutability for each possible use.  (I hope it's obvious that last part is sarcasm and not a serious suggestion).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "duplicate" fields, but the point remains, an `enum` value is constant, and you can't have the same enum value with different "states". Based on your example code, it looks like what you really want is not an `enum`, but just an instance of a regular `class`.